# How to add new SelectListItem dropdown in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, razor

What would be the most ideal way to add a new SelectListItem dropdown option based on a button click.

Whay would be best practice? I've considered the following options and wondered whether they would be ideal. Would duplicating a pre-existing row and assigning it a new ID be a worthwhile approach? Perhaps a partial view?

Does anyone have thoughts on the best practice way to do this? I would ideally like to avoid using jQuery heavily,perhaps maybe just to perform basic functions and instead have c# and .net handle more of the work.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to bind the selectlist values one by one to post the old list. You could try following sample:
Itemlist.cs

```
    public class Itemlist
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

IndexViewModel.cs

```
    public class IndexViewModel
    {
        public string Selected { get; set; }
        public List<Itemlist> List1 { get; set; }
    }
```

HomeController

```
        public IActionResult Index(IndexViewModel? model)
        {
            if (model.List1 == null)
            {
                model = new IndexViewModel()
                {
                    List1 = new List<Itemlist>()
                        {
                                new Itemlist { Text = "Physics", Value = "Physics" },
                                new Itemlist { Text = "Maths", Value = "Maths" },
                        }
                };
            }
            return View(model);
        }

        public IActionResult AddSelect(IndexViewModel model,string newOption)
        {
            if (!model.List1.Any(x => x.Text == newOption)&&(newOption!=null))
            {
                model.List1.Add(new Itemlist { Text = newOption, Value = newOption });
            }
            return View("Index", model);
        }
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model IndexViewModel

<form asp-controller="home">

    <select asp-for="Selected" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.List1, "Value", "Text"))"></select>

    new option: <input name="newOption" />


    @for(int i = 0; i < Model.List1.Count; i++)
    {
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.List1[i].Text" />
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.List1[i].Value" />
    }     

    <input type="submit" asp-action="AddSelect" value="Add Option"/>   
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Select" />

</form>
    You Select:  @Model.Selected
```

Test
[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for your assistance - much appreciated. However, I am trying insert a Selectlistitem drop-down box when the button is pressed, not an item within the box itself